# Car still vibrates after rotation and alignment

Tags: tires, hyundai, vibration, shaking, santa-fe

So I drive a 2010 Hyundai Sante Fe and a few months ago I noticed that it was vibrating while I was driving…took it to a mechanic, he told me nothing was wrong it’s vibrating because my axel was previously replaced with “non Hyundai parts” …fast forward to now it’s shaking/vibrating even worse and I’ve already done a wheel alignment, tire rotation and then replaced the back two tires. I will add that I also noticed that my car bounces…kind of like a bus ride but it’s not all the time. And I feel the vibrations mainly towards the front sometimes in the pedals. So I have no clue what else to even try next

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Does the vibration start/stop at a certain speed? Can you tell which corner of the car the vibration is coming from? I would disagree with the mechanic in their diagnosis of it being a drive axle *just because it wasn't from Hyundai*. Not saying it *isn't* the axle, I'm saying their reasoning is off-point and wrong. Anything within the realm of the drive train could be causing your issue, from a thrown wheel weight to a bad brake rotor. Might even be a bad shock which isn't dampening something like it should be.

Comment: Well the vibration seems to be in the front of the car and I’d say it more on the right side. And no it doesn’t start at a certain speed. As soon as I put my foot on the gas it starts.

Comment: Idk if if this helps but my two back rotors are rusty I’m not sure if that has anything to do with it

Comment: Rust alone on the rotor isn't going to cause you balance issues.  Have you checked the front tires to see if they are out of round? This can happen from a slipped belt in the tire which would produce vibration no matter how fast you are going. Is the rate at which you feel the "bounce" (as you put it) increase as the speed gets faster? Or can you feel it if you put your feet on the brake and gas at the same time (engine revs but car doesn't go anywhere)?

Comment: I mean I had Firestone look at my tires but idk they never told me anything was wrong , I had that lil inspection they do and the alignment and all…the result was just one lug nut missing on my RR tire but I’ve replaced that since then

Comment: And I really notice the bumpiness whenever I’m going over holes in the road… but it’ll even bounce over the tiniest hole. Even on smooth roads it’s still vibrating

Comment: Two things: do the bounce test on all four corners to test the shocks/struts; check the shocks/struts to see if you can detect any fluid leakage.

Comment: May be a dumb question but how do I do that?? Or do I have to take it somewhere for them to perform those tests

Comment: Literally, bounce each corner of the vehicle. Push the corner of the vehicle up and down several times until it gets into a rhythmic motion. Once it is moving like this, release the car and let it bounce. It should settle out within one cycle (should not continue to bounce). If it just continues to bob up and down, the strut/shock is bad. If this is the case, you should replace these in pairs at a minimum, and preferably all four.at the same time.

Comment: Okay thanks I will be trying that as soon as I get out of work!

Answer (score 0):

Your mechanic told you it's a bad axle. This fits with the symptoms you are experiencing.   This won't be fixed by an alignment or tire balance.

Comment: The mechanic didn't tell him it was a bad axle, but one which wasn't stock. This isn't a clear indication of where the vibration is coming from.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 the mechanic literally told him why it's vibrating

Comment: That's not what the mechanic told him. The OP said the mechanic told him "it’s vibrating because my axel was previously replaced with non Hyundai parts" ... this is plainly inaccurate on the mechanic's part. Just because an axle is not OEM does not mean it is defective and/or out of balance. It just isn't so.

Answer (score 0):

Aftermarket axles can cause this due to being solid and not hollow.
Their extra mass will exasperate all driveline balancing issues.
best of luck

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).